# Отправка смс на сервер

Tags: android

Как реализовать отправку всех смс с телефона на сервер?

Answer (score 0):

вам нужно опросить Content provider по нужному адресу, к примеру все входящие смс **"content://sms/inbox"**
взято из https://stackoverflow.com/a/18353829/5490632

```
public List<String> getSMS(){
        List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

        while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
            String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
            String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);  
        }

        if (cur != null) {
            cur.close();
        }
        return sms;
    }
```

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, но как тут происходит отправка всех смс на сервер?

Comment: Это метод для получения списка всех SMS. Чтобы отправить их на сервер, нужно написать еще и отправку этого списка куда-то.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос действительно странный: никто не знает что за сервер у вас. Наверное  вы знаете что у каждого сервера есть свой протокол обмена с клиентом. Без знания протокола сервера никто вам не скажет как отправить данные на этот сервер. Вопрос звучит примерно так:

> Как отправить булку хлеба инопланетянам

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос нужно понимать каков протокол обмена материалами с инопланетянами, то ли это телепортация, то ли через дыру в пространственно-временном континууме или надо зайти за гараж и там отдать в руки зеленому человечку в синей курточке.

Предыдущий автор в меру своих сил и способностей описал как взять весь список СМСок, наивно предполагая, что вы знаете протокол обмена с сервером...

Comment: Да прошлой автор, даже подумывать не мог, что его ждёт